# C - Function not terminating at end of input string leading to segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

Disclaimer: This is part of a homework assignment, however it is not the whole assignment.

I've been tasked to create a "tokenizer" object that retrieves tokens delimited by white space by returning them once per call to TKGetNextToken, and perform a series of operations on the tokens that were returned.

The TKGetNextToken function is not behaving as it should, though. What should happen is:

1. Advance through the input string until a non-white space character is found.
2. Continue advancing through the input string until white space or NULL (indicating the end of the string) is encountered, adding the characters to a new c string as it goes
3. If white space is encountered, the c string is returned and the current position within the string is saved within the TokenizerT struct.
4. If NULL is encountered, the c string is returned, and NULL is stored in the TokenizerT struct so that all following calls to TKGetNextToken returns NULL.

However, the function does not stop at the end of the string and instead just blows right past it and prints out everything in memory until the program crashes. I can't figure out why this is happening.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct TokenizerT_ {
    char *currentToken;
};

typedef struct TokenizerT_ TokenizerT;


char *TKGetNextToken(TokenizerT *tk) {
    char *cp = tk->currentToken;

    while (cp != NULL && isspace(*cp)) {
        cp++;
    }

    if (cp == NULL) {
        tk->currentToken = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }

    int size = 0;
    char *token = malloc(sizeof(char));

    while (cp != NULL && !isspace(*cp)) {
        size++;
        token = realloc(token, size * sizeof(char));
        token[size - 1] = *cp;
        cp++;
    }

    token = realloc(token, (size + 1) * sizeof(char));
    token[size] = NULL;

    tk->currentToken = cp;
    return token;
}

TokenizerT *TKCreate(char *ts) {
    TokenizerT *tokenizer = malloc(sizeof(TokenizerT));
    tokenizer->currentToken = ts;

    return tokenizer;
}

void TKDestroy(TokenizerT *tk) {
    free(tk);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    TokenizerT *tok = TKCreate(argv[1]);
    char *token = TKGetNextToken(tok);

    while (token) {
        printf("\'%s\'\n", token);
        token = TKGetNextToken(tok);
    }

    TKDestroy(tok);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample output given the command line argument "100 200 300 400". It's clearly printing from memory outside of the input string.

```
'100'
'200'
'300'
'400'
''
'╘jÉ'
'╘hÉ'
''
''
''
''
''
```

And output from gdb

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00401476 in TKGetNextToken (tk=0x701720) at test.c:28
28          while (cp != NULL && !isspace(*cp)) {
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00401476 in TKGetNextToken (tk=0x701720) at test.c:28
#1  0x0040151e in main (argc=2, argv=0x700cf0) at test.c:60
```

Comment: "the function does not stop at the end of the string " --> there is no code to test for end of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your two `while` loops, the condition ought to include a test for the null character. The appropriate test for "haven't encountered the null character at the end of the string" is `*cp`, used thus:

```
while ( cp != NULL && *cp && !isspace( *cp ) )
```

I get the feeling that the `cp != NULL` tests are a no-more-tokens test, in which case they should probably be factored out of the `while` loops. If that's wrong and they're the end-of-string test, they should be replaced by the `*cp` test.

Comment: You are right that I needed to check for the null character instead of checking if the address pointed to NULL. I needed to replace my `cp == NULL checks` with `*cp == '\0'` as just `*cp` checks didn't work for me. Thanks for your help!